# Reflection, get key-value pair of generic dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, reflection

How can i get the Key for a specific MyData.Name value?
I dont need to modify the Dictionary

This is the given situation and i need to match "Server" to 1L

```
public class MyBase
{
    protected struct MyData
    {
        public string Name;
    }
}

public class MyClass : MyBase
{
    private readonly Dictionary<ulong, MyBase.MyData> m_Data = new Dictionary<ulong, MyBase.MyData>();
    public MyClass()
    {
        m_Data.Add(1L, new MyData { Name = "Server" });
    }
}

public class MyMulti
{
    public static MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
}

public class Test
{

    Type MyDataType = typeof(MyBase).GetNestedType("MyData", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    object m_Data = typeof(MyClass).GetField("m_Data", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(MyMulti.myClass);

    // How can i get the Key for a specific MyData.Name value?
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?? Why do you need reflection to do that

Comment: @EmrahSüngü i needed this for a plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actualy just found an easy way to do so:

```
var m_Data = typeof(MyClass).GetField("m_Data", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(MyMulti.myClass) as IDictionary;


foreach (var pair in m_Data.Keys)
{
  Console.WriteLine(pair + " = " + m_Data[pair].GetType().GetField("Name").GetValue(m_Data[pair]));
}
```